# Adding border on border radius image background bleed through

Tags: html, css

I'm adding a black border on images with a blue background and while doing so, it appears to add an ever so noticeable background colored outline on the INSIDE of the border when doing so. Is there a way to get rid of this? The code I'm using is simple:

```
border-radius: 100%;
border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

And you can see the background color edging in by adding a radius to any image, as an example:

[image]

Comment: Is this browser specific?

Comment: @zgood - No it is not browser specific.

Comment: thats the only code you have in your CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to avoid that annoying border-radius background bleed:

#### Method 1: Wrapper with Background Color

Put the `<img>` in a wrapper element, and add padding to the wrapper, with a background color that matches the `<img>`'s border. This way, any antialiasing that happens on the image will take into account the background color of the wrapper, rather than the background color of the page.

#### Method 2: Add Background Color to Image

Add a background color to your `<img>` that matches the border color. It'll use the `<img>`'s background color instead of the page background color to do the antialiasing.

#### Method 3: Use Padding Instead

Don't bother with a border. Add padding to your `<img>` equal to the border size you want, and add a background color in the border color you want. This gets you the same effect with the least amount of code.

---

Here's a JSFiddle with each of these methods: https://jsfiddle.net/4zpL98au/14/

Comment: Looks like you edited your answer with a jsfiddle as I was looking into it myself.  Great solution!

Answer (score 3):

@stvnrynlds gave an interesting answer and I wanted to test this out myself with actual code.

I have created a snippet below with both versions for comparison.

.test1 - uses padding with a wrapper instead of a border

.test2 - uses border only

```css
.test1{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:5px;
  background:black;
}

.test1 img{
  border-radius:50%;
}

.test2 img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4LM6DpN.gif"/></div>
<div class="test2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4LM6DpN.gif"/></div>
```

Zooming in 500% into the browser you can see the end results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite simple solution for this problemen, just by adding a background color:

```
background:#000;
border-radius: 100%;
border: 3px solid #000;
```

[image]

Comment: OP's solution included an image